# How to read the flags registers in x86 processor

Tags: assembly, x86

Are there any assembly instructions to let us directly read or write the overflow  flag in Intel's 80386 16-bit Flags register ? If not, what pseudo code should we use?

Comment: One can use pushf and popf to save/restore them using stack. (popfd, popfq restore the 32-bit and 64-bit extensions of the EFLAGS / RFLAGS respectively)

Answer (score 8):

To read only the overflow flag:

```
SETO AL
; AL now contains 1 if the overflow flag was set, and 0 if it wasn't
```

To invert the overflow flag:

```
PUSHF
POP    AX
XOR    AX,800h  ; The overflow flag is in bit 11
PUSH   AX
POPF
```

Comment: The OP is asking for 16-bit FLAGS; your code is 32-bit. -1 for not reading the question.

Comment: That's a fairly minor detail to get hung up on considering that it should be obvious how to make the same code 16-bit. Edited the answer anyway.

Comment: That obviously wasn't the case since the question title only mentions reading the flags. I simply overlooked one detail when writing my initial answer, which I honestly don't think made the example "not useful".

Answer (score 1):

To read the flags into `AX`:

```
pushf
pop ax
```

To write the flags: if you need to set/clear specific bits, there are some commands like `stc/clc` (for Carry flag), `std/cld` (for Direction) and so forth; but not bits are exposed this way. To write the whole flags register, use

```
push ax
popf
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
Pushf
// modify or read ax register
Popf
```

Comment: `pushf` writes eflags to the stack, not to `ax`.